# Source code for uniq method in Ruby

Tags: ruby

In pry I'm typing

```
Array.instance_method(:uniq).source_location
```

Expected : source code location for uniq

Actual: `nil`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To see source code you can look at [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Source-browsing#Show_method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to re-read the doc on [`Method#source_location`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Method.html#method-i-source_location):

> Returns the Ruby source filename and line number containing this method or nil if this method was not defined in Ruby (**i.e. native**)

Array as you might notice in the top-left corner of this doc page, is defined in `proc.c`, that said it’s methods *are native*.

Comment: Is there a way to find the source location for native methods?

Comment: @RailsOuter: Try here http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq and click "toggle source" . . . do note it is C and if you want to trace it completely you will need to access the source for the Ruby interpreter e.g. at http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source  if you want the source programmatically, then I don't think it is possible simply.

Answer (score 2):

`Method#source_location` returns the location of the *Ruby* source code. Depending on the Ruby implementation you are using, there may not *be* Ruby source code. In MRI, YARV, MRuby, or tinyrb, the method may be implemented in C, in XRuby or JRuby, it may be implemented in Java, in Ruby.NET or IronRuby, it may be implemented in C#, in MagLev, it may be implemented in Smalltalk, in MacRuby or RubyMotion, it may be implemented in Objective-C, in Topaz, it may be implemented in RPython, in Cardinal, it may be implemented in Perl6, and in Rubinius, it may be implemented in C++.

However, in Rubinius, many more methods are implemented in Ruby than in other Ruby implementations, so the chance that you will actually get a `source_location` is much greater. For example, this is what I get on Rubinius:

```
Array.instance_method(:uniq).source_location
# => ['kernel/common/array.rb', 1640]
```

This is what [`kernel/common/array.rb`](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/kernel/common/array.rb#L1701-1703) looks like (the code has changed since I compiled my version of Rubinius, that's why the line numbers don't match):

```
def uniq(&block)
  dup.uniq!(&block) or dup
end
```